# Apache Redirecting Domain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, redirect, domains

My second/new (site.com) domain is being redirected to the default/old domain (site.ca). However, when the url is entered with the SSL for the new domain it works just fine. When I use regular with http://, it redirects to my old domain (site.ca).

My configs are as follow: Non-SSL: http://pastebin.com/mKt2zuu8 SSL: http://pastebin.com/Lc1wA5PV

I am frustrated, I have spent over 4 hours trying to figure out what is wrong. I do have two dedicated IPs.

Comment: I see no rewrite statements. The Virtual Hosts seem okay

Comment: Please don't cross-post with SuperUser.com.

Comment: I still see no problem (or redirect) maybe it is the app/website that redirects you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Apache was not loading my conf file, after I moved it from an external .conf file straight into httpd.conf, my virtual host are working just fine.